# Can I cycle from Brig in Switzerland across Simplon pass to Lago Maggiore Italy?

Tags: italy, switzerland, bicycles

Google map seems to say I can cycle from Brig to the Zwischbergen (Italian border). Is this correct because the route does seem to go along the road E62?

What about the part from the border to Lago Maggiore. Is it possible to cycle that route?

Here pictures from Google maps.

[image: Brig to Zwischbergen]

[image: Brig to Zwischbergen detail]

Comment: While google does cycling these days, they do not guaranty that the routes they show are suitable or bike tracks/paths, a bike dedicated planner or following a long distance route for cycling might be better.

Comment: An E- route is not necessarily an Autobahn or other restricted-access street - it is just a cross-country long distance route naming convention. The Simplon Pass is State Street 9 in Switzerland, and SS33 in Italy, and it is a normal country road.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can cycle over the Simplon. Source: I've done it myself.

In the lower parts, where there are motorways closed for bicycles, you always have a parallel road open for cyclists.

No problem to cycle from Brig to Lago Maggiore.

A picture from when I was there:

[image]